# Prove that this module homomorphism is surjective but not injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Consider an A-module M. Define $\phi : A^n \to M$ by $ \phi :e_i \to m_i$ and $\phi_1 (a_1,...,a_n) = a_1 m_1+ ...+ a_n m_n$ Prove that $\phi_1$ is a module homomorphism , surjective but not injective where {$m_1,...,m_n$} is generating set of Module M.

I have proved it to be module homomorphism, but I am unable to prove it to be surjective and not  injective.

I am clueless on how to prove it surjective and I tried following in proving it injective.

Let $\phi(a_1,...,a_n) =\phi(b_1,...,b_n) $ which implies that $a_1m_1+...+a_nm_n= b_1m_1+...+ b_n m_n$ which implies that $(a_1-b_1)m_1 +...+(a_n-b_n)m_n=0$ but I am unable to prove that it will not necessarily imply 1-1.

Comment: *Hint*: What is the meaning of the sentence "$\{m_1,\dots,m_n\}$ is a generating set of $M$"?

Comment: You can't prove that it's always not injective, as in the case $M=A^n,\ m_i=e_i$ this map is clearly isomorphism. However, you can also find an *example* when $\phi$ is not injective.

Comment: @Berci Ya, Ok Can you please help with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's given in the text that $\{m_1,...,m_m\}$ is generating set of module $M$. This means we can write $M=\{\sum_{i=1}^na_im_i:a_i\in A\}$.

Now, showing surjectivity follows trivially. If $m\in M$ is arbitrary, then $m\in M$ implies $m\in \{\sum_{i=1}^na_im_i:a_i\in A\}$, so $m=\sum_{i=1}^na_im_i$ for some $a_i's$ in $A$. Hence, $\phi(a_1,...,a_n)=m$, and this shows surjectivity of $\phi$.

With the given information, we can't say $\phi$ is not injective. $\phi$ may be injective or not injective depending on $M$. If $M$ equals to $A^n$ and $m_i=e_i$, then $\phi$ is just the identity mapping, and this is clearly bijective. On the other hand, if $M=A$ and $m_1=\cdots=m_n=e_1$, then $\phi$ is clearly not injective as $\phi(e_1)=\phi(e_2)=e_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\phi: A^2\to A^1$ sending $e_1\mapsto e_1$ and $e_2\mapsto e_1$. Now observe $\phi(e_1-e_2)=0$.

So in general $\phi$ may not be injective.

Also, $\phi$ is surjective.

Also in your original question (you can check) $\phi$ is surjective iff the set $\{m_1,\dots,m_n\}$ is a generating set for $M$.

Comment: Can you please help on how should I proceed on proving that $\phi$ is not surjective?

Comment: See that $e_2$ is not in the image of $\phi$.

Comment: @ Evans I was asking how it's surjective. I am unable to understand how your comments helps with that.

Comment: You are right. I meant to give the target for $\phi$ as $A$ just one copy of $A.$